# Encrypted Booting

Tags: security, boot, encryption

I want to boot the Linux from the /boot partition, and also want to encrypt this /boot partition.

[ AFAIK, Grub is unable to find the kernel and initrd from an truecrypted partition or cryptsetup encrypted boot partition. ]

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Just one remark -- encrypting entire system except /boot is supported by default. This means, that if you fall into problem with your system, you probably fix it easier than in case with /boot encrypted as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using Grub2 you can do this: It has been patched to support not only AES, Twofish, Serpent and CAST5 encryption, but a number of hashing routines such as SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, and RIPEMD160. There is also support for the LUKS on-disk encryption format.

Check out [**this xercestech post**](http://xercestech.com/full-system-encryption-for-linux.geek) for a full manual walkthrough, but in a nutshell everything is encrypted except for the actual bootloader, which you could have on a USB stick if you really wanted to stay safe.

The LUKS patches to support grub are [**here.**](http://michael.gorven.za.net/bzr/grub/luks.)

Comment: Thanks Rory.... I will follow the tutorial and will give you feedback. BTW, the link is broken, it seems. If you have the http://michael.gorven.za.net/bzr/grub/luks., please do share with us.

Comment: Trim the period off the end of that URL and it will work.